# Why might the App Store draw variable-type strings in place of actual values?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, software-update

I have just formatted my drive, and performed a fresh install of Mac OS X Mountain Lion from USB flash drive. When doing my first Software Update, within the App Store application, under the Updates section, the first listed update is the weird looking string "DAHSoftwareUpdate" with title field having the value "DAHSoftwareUpdatesPage.OSUpdates.Title".

Underneath this title, is the correct name of the update (OS X Update Combined 10.8.2, iTunes 11.0.1. Also under the progress bar I see FileSize.MB of FileSize.MB, then the remaining time in minutes.

This seemed odd to me, especially after I get zero google results for "DAHSoftwareUpdate" or even "SoftwareUpdatesPage.OSUpdates.Title".

One possibility, that seems extremely remote, is that the MountainLion.dmg which has been moved around between my backup drives a lot, might have been corrupted, and I'm seeing a weird bug in the AppStore app as a result. It seems much more likely that this is a result of something like a bad localization/language setting, but that would not account for the zero hits for the variable names showing.

Can someone explain what's going on here?

Comment: There is a lot of checksumming that goes on when you open DMGs and apps, so corruption seems unlikely. Did you try rebooting or waiting a few hours? A lot of App Store/iTunes Store bugs go away like that.

Comment: Thanks @KevinChen. I did try a reboot before applying the update, with no effect. 
But now, after applying the update everything seems back to normal. 
Still, it's left me curious ..

Comment: I have it to, on a machine which was not recently installed. Weird

Comment: @jaysen if this resolved itself, we encourage you to answer explaining what happened (x amount of time passed, update Fnished installing after a reboot , whatever else) and resolved itself. You can then come back and accept it or edit it if it reappears. This way others will know not to offer suggestions (but can still answer the what happened if they know). Thanks and welcome to the site n

Comment: i just saw this now

Answer (score 1):

This issue resolved itself after that single update. 
I did reboot once without updating, and the glitch persisted past that boot, but after the update in question was done and the laptop rebooted, there was no recurrence.

As for the likelihood of a corrupted installer dmg, @KevinChen points out that "there is a lot of checksumming that goes on when you open DMGs and apps, so corruption seems unlikely"

Comment: I was just curious about not finding any references to an obvious variable name, and to whether that is normal within the (perhaps very closed source) MacOs ecosystem?

Is this a case of business as usual, and variable names used inside closed software would barely register a google hit, or is this just a weird example that has not previously been brought up ??


I've since found http://bugreporter.apple.com/ but I'm less inclined to contribute, then with other more publicly accessible bug reports.

Also, I'm sorry for not taking a screenshot.

Comment: pretty suspicious, huh.